# Radio button under image sliders with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Currently the image slider is fix width a radio button is position by line-height. If the image width is switch to 100%, how do The radio button remain at the bottom of the image in responsive layout?

**CSS**

```
.slideshow{
  width:640px;
  height:360px;
  max-height:760px;

  position:relative;
  text-align:center;.slideshow {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  max-height: 760px;

  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.slideshow input[type="radio"] {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 1em;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out background, 0.3s ease-out transform;
}

.slideshow input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background: #999;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out opacity;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 88;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label:after {
  display: block;
  content: "\25B6";
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous {
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;.slideshow {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  max-height: 760px;

  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.slideshow input[type="radio"] {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 1em;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out background, 0.3s ease-out transform;
}

.slideshow input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background: #999;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out opacity;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 88;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label:after {
  display: block;
  content: "\25B6";
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous {
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label.next {
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}
.slideshow input[type="radio"]:checked + .slideshow-item {
  opacity: 1;
}

}
.slideshow .slideshow-item label.next {
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}
.slideshow input[type="radio"]:checked + .slideshow-item {
  opacity: 1;
}

  line-height:75px;padding-bottom:30px}.slideshow input[type=radio]{
    font-size:.75em;
    width:1em;height:1em;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:99;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none;background:#ccc;border-radius:1em;transition:.3s ease-out background,.3s ease-out transform}

.slideshow input[type=radio]:checked{
    background:#999;outline:0;-webkit-transform:scale(1.3);-moz-transform:scale(1.3);transform:scale(1.3)}.slideshow .slideshow-item{width:640px;height:360px;line-height:1.5;position:absolute;top:0;opacity:0;transition:.3s ease-out opacity}.slideshow .slideshow-item label{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;width:50%;display:none;z-index:88;cursor:pointer;color:transparent;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.slideshow .slideshow-item label:after{display:block;content:'\25B6';font-size:2em;color:#fff;position:absolute;top:50%;right:10px;margin-top:-.5em}.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous{left:0;display:block}.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous:after{-webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);-moz-transform:scaleX(-1);transform:scaleX(-1);right:auto;left:10px}.slideshow .slideshow-item label.next{left:50%;display:block}.slideshow input[type=radio]:checked+.slideshow-item{opacity:1}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
  <h1>Pure CSS slideshow</h1>
  <p>A proof of concept to have an image slideshow without javascript</p>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="item-1" checked="checked" />
    <div class="slideshow-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/sports/1" />
      <label for="item-3" class="previous">Go to slide 3</label>
      <label for="item-2" class="next">Go to slide 2</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="item-2" />
    <div class="slideshow-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/sports/2" />
      <label for="item-1" class="previous">Go to slide 1</label>
      <label for="item-3" class="next">Go to slide 3</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="slide" id="item-3" />
    <div class="slideshow-item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/sports/3" />
      <label for="item-2" class="previous">Go to slide 2</label>
      <label for="item-1" class="next">Go to slide 1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>By <a href="https://twitter.com/joggink">@joggink</a> | <a href="https://github.com/joggink/pure-css-slideshow">View on github</a></p>
</div>
```

[Link Here](https://codepen.io/proyb2/pen/KRqWGG)

Answer (score 1):

if your slideshow height is fixed using can use CSS translateY. [codepen](https://codepen.io/arpanpatel/pen/bMRRzB)

```css
.slideshow{
  width:100%;
  height:360px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom:30px;
background-color:green;
}

.slideshow input[type=radio]{
    font-size:.75em;
    width:1em;
  height:1em;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
      transform: translateY(360px);
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius:1em;
transition:.3s ease-out background,.3s ease-out transform
}

.slideshow input[type=radio]:checked{
    background:#999;outline:0;transform: translateY(360px) scale(1.3)}


.slideshow-item{
  width:100%;
  height:360px;
  line-height:1.5;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  opacity:0;
  transition:.3s ease-out opacity}

.slideshow .slideshow-item label{
 position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50%;
  display:none;
  z-index:88;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.slideshow .slideshow-item label:after{display:block;content:'\25B6';font-size:2em;color:#fff;position:absolute;top:50%;right:10px;margin-top:-.5em}.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous{left:0;display:block}.slideshow .slideshow-item label.previous:after{-webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);-moz-transform:scaleX(-1);transform:scaleX(-1);right:auto;left:10px}.slideshow .slideshow-item label.next{left:50%;display:block}.slideshow input[type=radio]:checked+.slideshow-item{opacity:1}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="slideshow">
<input type="radio" name="slide" id="item-1" checked="checked" />
<div class="slideshow-item">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/sports/1" />
<label for="item-3" class="previous">Go to slide 3</label>
<label for="item-2" class="next">Go to slide 2</label>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="slide" id="item-2" />
<div class="slideshow-item">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/sports/2" />
<label for="item-1" class="previous">Go to slide 1</label>
<label for="item-3" class="next">Go to slide 3</label>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="slide" id="item-3" />
<div class="slideshow-item">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/360/sports/3" />
<label for="item-2" class="previous">Go to slide 2</label>
<label for="item-1" class="next">Go to slide 1</label>
</div>
</div>
<p>By <a href="https://twitter.com/joggink">@joggink</a> | <a href="https://github.com/joggink/pure-css-slideshow">View on github</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: If I don’t have a fix height, I assume if your solution also apply to responsive on mobile device?

Comment: Let me check for responsive

Comment: I afraid it's not. for responsive slide, you need to use javascript to calculating slider height

Comment: No problem, i think is DIV around each radio buttons could do?

Comment: sorry @JamesLei, but i don't understand

Comment: Sorry, I mean I placed <div><input type=radio></div> with DIV around and apply height to 100% but would this workable for radio button to move to the bottom? One of my hacky code: https://codepen.io/proyb2/pen/KRqWGG

Comment: hey @JamesLei you can do this. add following  line to .rdown class `display: inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-end;`

Comment: it move radios button down.